# Flutter gives Exception caught by rendering library and List doesn't show up

Tags: flutter, macos

I want to make an App that shows different products and their healthiness but ran into this Problem. Main.dart gets shown but list.dart not. Im programming in Android Studio and I am a beginners and don't know very much about Flutter, Dart or Android Studio.

Error:

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.

This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is: RenderIndexedSemantics#f3c2e relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  parentData: index=0; layoutOffset=0.0 (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: MISSING
...  index: 0
The constraints that applied to the RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox were: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
The exact size it was given was: Size(411.4, Infinity)

See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints for more information.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold Scaffold:file:///Users/jan/StudioProjects/nutricalculator/lib/list.dart:14:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      RenderBox.debugAssertDoesMeetConstraints.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2258:9)
#1      RenderBox.debugAssertDoesMeetConstraints (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2352:6)
#2      RenderBox.size=.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2044:7)
#3      RenderBox.size= (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2046:6)
#4      RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:402:5)
#5      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#6      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#7      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#8      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#9      _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1376:11)
#10     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#11     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#13     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#14     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#15     RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:213:28)
#16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#17     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:137:12)
#18     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:371:11)
#19     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#20     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:510:13)
#21     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1580:12)
#22     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1489:20)
#23     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#24     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#25     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#26     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#27     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#28     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#29     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#30     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#31     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#32     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#33     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#34     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#35     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#36     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#37     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#38     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#39     RenderCustomPaint.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:545:11)
#40     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#41     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#42     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#43     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:12)
#44     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:1005:7)
#45     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
#46     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:403:14)
#47     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#48     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#49     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#50     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#51     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1376:11)
#52     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#53     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#54     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#55     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#56     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#57     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#58     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#59     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#60     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#61     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#62     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#63     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#64     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#65     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#66     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#67     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#68     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#69     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#70     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3430:13)
#71     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#72     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#73     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#74     _RenderTheatre.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:751:15)
#75     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#76     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#77     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#78     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#79     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#80     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#81     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#82     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#83     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#84     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#85     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#86     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#87     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#88     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#89     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#90     RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:165:14)
#91     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1731:7)
#92     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:887:18)
#93     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:497:19)
#94     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:883:13)
#95     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
#96     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#97     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1081:9)
#98     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:862:7)
(elided 4 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox#b5a51 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: Size(411.4, Infinity)
RenderObject: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox#b5a51 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: Size(411.4, Infinity)
...  child 1: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#a92a4 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body
...    constraints: MISSING
...    size: MISSING
...    child: RenderMouseRegion#d1a5d NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: <none>
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      listeners: enter, exit
...      cursor: SystemMouseCursor(basic)
...      child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#34d26 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...        parentData: <none>
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        child: RenderPointerListener#9cf0e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...          parentData: <none>
...          constraints: MISSING
...          size: MISSING
...          behavior: opaque
...          listeners: down
...  child 2: RenderStack#f7934 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.floatingActionButton
...    constraints: MISSING
...    size: MISSING
...    alignment: Alignment.centerRight
...    textDirection: ltr
...    fit: loose
...    child 1: RenderTransform#3cb73 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: not positioned; offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      transform matrix: [0] 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
[1] 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
[2] 0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0
[3] 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
...      origin: null
...      alignment: Alignment.center
...      textDirection: ltr
...      transformHitTests: true
...      child: RenderTransform#369e5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...        parentData: <none>
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        transform matrix: [0] 0.7,0.7,0.0,0.0
[1] -0.7,0.7,0.0,0.0
[2] 0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0
[3] 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
...        origin: null
...        alignment: Alignment.center
...        textDirection: ltr
...        transformHitTests: true
====================================================================================================
```

This is my Code:

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:openfoodfacts/openfoodfacts.dart';
import 'list.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


void main(
    ) {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); //Entfernt die
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: [ //Status
  SystemUiOverlay.bottom,
  ]
  );
  runApp(
      MyApp(items: const [],),
  );
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> items;
  const MyApp ({Key? key, required this.items}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: ListView(
          children: const [
            MyList(),
          ],
        ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 60,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      title: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
        const Text('Produkte',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          Image.network('https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C4D0BAQEK3trT03gyQg/company-logo_200_200/0/1644614965433?e=2147483647&v=beta&t=RMW_ojn2kZSe1oYD_Br2PprreuPr4g5aP1J7_X201ms',
            height: 70,
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
    ],
      ),
    ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

list.dart

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    const MyList(),
  );
}

class MyList extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListTile(
        title: const Text('Prince Chocolat - LU - 300 g'),
        leading: SizedBox(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          child: Image.network('https://images.openfoodfacts.org/images/products/762/221/044/9283/front_fr.475.100.jpg'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind I found a solution.
For the people that have the same Problem change this inside the Script:

Main.dart

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: MyList(),
```

List.dart

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
       ListTile(
        title: const Text('Prince Chocolat - LU - 300 g'),
        leading: SizedBox(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          child: Image.network('https://images.openfoodfacts.org/images/products/762/221/044/9283/front_fr.475.100.jpg'),
        ),
    ),
      ]
    ),
    );
  }
}
```